# How do i Install and configure PowerPath in Windows environment

Tags: windows-server-2003, emc

How do i Install and configure PowerPath in Windows environment..can someone help me with screen shot or just walk me through the steps.

Will appreciate a quick response .
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EMC Powerlink contains documents that are exactly what you need: step-by-step walkthroughs.

Do a search on the site or reach out to your EMC contacts.

An alternative is to use one of the new tools provided for the specific storage model, like [this one](http://www.emc.com/cx4support), to build a customized document.